# Installing pyGPs - A Package for Gaussian Processes

Tags: 12.04, python, eclipse, python-2.7

I am doing a project which predicts expected electrical load every half an hour based on  Gaussian model of previous 1 year data.

I am currently using python 2.7.3 for implementing this project. For implementing Gaussian process I wanted to use package `pyGPs`. `pyGPs` is a library hosting Python implementations of Gaussian processes (GPs) for machine learning.

I have gone through net and I am not getting proper information about `pyGPs` installation in eclipse.
                                                                                           Any suggestions or advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To install the `pyGPs` python package, open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> and type the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-numpy python-scipy
wget https://github.com/marionmari/pyGPs/archive/v1.3.tar.gz
tar -zxvf v1.3.tar.gz
cd pyGPs-1.3
sudo python setup.py install
```

Now you can run a python interpreter to check that **pyGPs** is properly installed:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pyGPs
>>> import numpy as np
>>>
```

Comment: I was able to install it properly with addition of this command sudo apt-get install python-setuptools . If this error is their "Your setup.py file needs setuptools" then before running setup.py then the command mentioned above should be executed first.For more information check out this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools.Thank you.